# I'm trying to get every combination of color and value and I don't know how to use the function islice

Tags: python

```
from itertools import islice
colur={"S", "H", "D", "C"}
val={"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"}
for c in islice(colur,0,4):
 for v in islice(val,0,13):
  print( c,v )
```

I want it to print
S2
S3
S4
S5
S6
S7
S8
....

Comment: Do you need to use the function `islice`?

Comment: why do you think `islice` helps you with this problem? why not just a nested `for` loop?

Comment: also, are you aware that the sets you are using may not be in the order as you typed them in?

Comment: and finally, you did not tell us about any problem with your code.

Comment: If you don't need to use islice, I think itertools.product would be best to use in this situation

Comment: problem is every time I run it it gives me a different value for c and a different value for v

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better option than islice

Comment: I just triedI just tried  print( product(colur,val) ) And all it gave me was <itertools.product object at 0x7f7f4a6a0480> I have no idea how to use this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
from itertools import product
colur={"S", "H", "D", "C"}
val={"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"}
combinations = [f'{i[0]}{i[1]}' for i in product(colur, val)]

for i in combinations:
    print(i)
```

If you want your original order to be respected, change sets for lists (sets are unordered):

```
colur=["S", "H", "D", "C"]
val=["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
combinations = [f'{i[0]}{i[1]}' for i in product(colur, val)]
```